# Reading/Writing database error

Tags: java, android, file

I have a read and write operation at a android app. On onCreate, a file will be read and display it to an editext and can be editted. When the save is pressed, the data will be written to the same file that will be read on onCreate. But I got an error. No such file in directory. I don't get it. I'm creating the file when the save button is pressed. Any ideas?

Java code:

```
 EditText Name;
 EditText Age;
 EditText Height;
 EditText Weight;
 EditText MedHistory;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_medicalhistory);

     Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.medhistName);
     Age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.medhistAge);
     Height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.medhistHeight);
     Weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.medhistWeight);
     MedHistory = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MedHist);

     int i = 0;

     String MedHistData[] = new String[5];

     try {
            File myFile = new File("/data/data/Project.Package.Structure/files/MedicalHistory.txt");
            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
            String aDataRow = "";
            while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                MedHistData[i] = aDataRow;
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;
            Name.setText(MedHistData[0]);
            Age.setText(MedHistData[1]);
            Height.setText(MedHistData[2]);
            Weight.setText(MedHistData[3]);
            MedHistory.setText(MedHistData[4]);
            myReader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


     Button Save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveBtn);
     Save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                File myFile = new File("/data/data/Project.Package.Structure/files/MedicalHistory.txt");
                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                myOutWriter.append(Name.getText() + "\n");
                myOutWriter.append(Age.getText() + "\n");
                myOutWriter.append(Height.getText() + "\n");
                myOutWriter.append(Weight.getText() + "\n");
                myOutWriter.append(MedHistory.getText());
                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Medical History Saved'",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        }); 

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use openFileInput() method to open file for reading and openFileOutput() for writing. These functions return a FileInputStream and FileOutputStream respectively.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: you don't have write access to the file.
You only can access specific folders for writing in android.
Have a look at

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

They have a simple example on how to write a text file.

Comment: I've seen articles use this approach and got them to work. I just don't know the problem of mine's,

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the stacktrace and point out the line number, the cause of the exception states?